# Firebase Realtime database not updating

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage

My problem is that firebase realtime database does not update. Authentication and storage do, they are working without problem. The rules are set to "true". It is weird because my app has the functionality to edit your user information and display it on profile, and that works,the input shows on the app, but the data is nowhere to be found in Firebase. I don't know where the problem could be.

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ('**why isn't this code working?**') must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)"

Comment: Please edit your question and add the information Frank asked for, and please also respond using @.